# Android enable face unlock to application

Tags: android, unlock, face

I want to enable fingerprint and face unlock for my application. I have fingerprint unlock code and it is working fine if the user is already registered his fingerprint.

I want to enable the same feature for face unlock as well. If the user has already enrolled his face id , then he should be able to authenticate the app with face unlock.I don't want to create any library here, I just want to invoke the device face unlock app and authenticate.

Please give me the suggestion

Comment: what device face unlock app?

Comment: @Nikos - I need to use phone default face recognition/face unlock

Comment: I'm not aware of a default one in android. Also other than the new Samsung models I can't think of many others that offer face recognition. That's why I'm wondering what device face unlock app you're talking about.

Comment: @Nik- Like Samsung new models, other companies like oppo, realme,one plus have their Face recognition apps. Is there anyway to invoke/access this samsung face recognition in android apps (Like we enable Fingerprint auth for banking apps)

Comment: There's no API in Android for doing a face authentication specifically. If you use `BiometricPrompt`, it _may_ end up using face authentication if the device supports it and the user has enrolled their face in the Settings app. But you as the app developer have no control over that. I filed [an issue regarding this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111315641) about a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

May be useful for someone: https://developer.android.com/training/sign-in/biometric-auth
The Biometric library expands upon the functionality of the deprecated FingerprintManager API.

Comment: Unfortunately this API is still tricky, bugged and insecure as of 2022. There are critical errors like the fallback button triggering a CANCEL event in Android 10.